# jQuery: Adding a setting to the Ajax function

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm disabling a button before every ajax call, and re-enabling it once the call is compete. I'm doing this like:

```
jQuery.fn.buttonDisable = function(v) {

    if(v)
        $(this).prop('disabled', true).addClass('animate-load').parents('html').addClass('busy');
    else
        $(this).prop('disabled', false).removeClass('animate-load').parents('html').removeClass('busy');

};


$('.element button').buttonDisable(true);

$.ajax({
    type: "post",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/api/login",
    data: {
        username :  username.val(),
        password : password.val(),
    }
})
.done(function(data) {

    $('.element button').buttonDisable(false);

    ...
```

Would it be possible to pass a parameter into the ajax function and have this automated? Something like:

```
$.ajax({
    button: $('.element button'),

    ...
```

So this would run the following before the ajax call starts:

```
    $('.element button').prop('disabled', true).addClass('animate-load').parents('html').addClass('busy');
```

And once complete, run:

```
    $('.element button').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('animate-load').parents('html').removeClass('busy');
```

Comment: not quite what youve asked for but this also works: https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/

Comment: I'm wanting to write the button disable and enable just once, and have it work any time I use a specific setting on an ajax function.

Comment: Also https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either of the other listed methods ([`.ajaxStart`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart) or [`$.ajaxSetup`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup))  will work fine to "globally" enhance ajax with that functionality, however I would suggest against this.  **EVERY** call to `$.ajax` will get passed through those methods, including calls done by third party libraries.  This might not be the desired behavior in the end.

If this were for any "large" project I would write my own `$.ajax` method that could be used anywhere I wanted that functionality, something like this:

```
(function ( $ ) {
  var root = $('html');

  function doAjax(options) {
    var jqXHR = $.ajax(options);

    if (options.disableSelection) {
      root.addClass('busy');
      options.disableSelection
        .prop('disabled', true).addClass('animate-load')

      jqXHR.always(function() {
        root.removeClass('busy');
        options.disableSelection
          .prop('disabled', false).removeClass('animate-load');
      });
    }

    return jqXHR;
  }

  window.doAjax = doAjax;
})(jQuery);
```

You can then replace `$.ajax` call that you want to have that functionality with `doAjax` instead of `$.ajax` and pass in your `disableSelection: $('.element button')`.

You also get passed the `options` in the jQuery global events (`.ajaxComplete` and `.ajaxStart`) as well as in the `beforeSend` and `complete` as `this` if you take the `$.ajaxSetup` route.

Also, maybe take a look at [`$.ajaxPrefilter`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter) you get access to everything in there.

```
(function ($) {
  // this value will never change, so why bother looking it up more than once
  var root = $('html'); 

  // we get to check the options of every $.ajax call, awesome!
  $.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, jqXHR) {

    if (options.disableSelection) {

      root.addClass('busy');
      options.disableSelection
        .prop('disabled', true).addClass('animate-load');

      jqXHR.always(function() {
        root.removeClass('busy');
        options.disableSelection
          .prop('disabled', false).removeClass('animate-load');
      });
    }

  });
})(jQuery);

// and then somewhere else when you make a call, pass disableSelection
$.ajax({
  type: "post",
  dataType: "json",
  url: "/api/login",
  // check out this method btw, it rules
  data: $('.element form').serialize(),
  disableSelection: $('.element button')
})
.done(function(data) {
  // ....
});
```

Both methods have their advantages, though I tend to prefer the `doAjax` method because it makes it obvious that there are options to this method that standard `jQuery.ajax` doesn't provide.  If you do decide to use a prefilter, and the code will be edited/worked on by multiple people, I highly suggest adding an obvious namespace to the `disableSelection` property, call it something like `myCompanyDisableSelection` so that someone can search the code base for that string rather than try reading jQuery documentation to figure out what the hell `disableSelection` does :)

Answer (score 1):

Rather than extending the ajax functionality I would rather use the jQuery [ajaxStart](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxComplete](https://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) callbacks:

```
jQuery.fn.buttonDisable = function(v) {

    if(v)
        $(this).prop('disabled', true).addClass('animate-load').parents('html').addClass('busy');
    else
        $(this).prop('disabled', false).removeClass('animate-load').parents('html').removeClass('busy');

};

$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
  $('.element button').buttonDisable(true);
});

$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $('.element button').buttonDisable(false);
});
```

By the way: `.parents('html')` is probably the most unperformant thing ever, use `$('html')` in the first place or at least `.closest('html')`.

This method would globally run the function. Use `beforeSend` and `complete` in the ajax call if you want to controll it individually.

Comment: Is there a better method to toggle this usage? Because there may be times when I'm making an ajax call but there is no button, or perhaps I don't want to disable/enable a button.

Comment: as i said, within your ajax call use the `beforeSend` property to define a function

Answer (score 1):

Try something like below:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "post",
        dataType: "json",
        url: "/api/login",
        data: {
            username: username.val(),
            password: password.val(),
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('.element button').prop('disabled', true).addClass('animate-load').parents('html').addClass('busy');
        },
        success: function () {
            $('.element button').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('animate-load').parents('html').removeClass('busy');
        },
    })
```

Comment: I don't want to keep repeating myself with the disable/enable on every ajax call. Would it be possible to append a setting through the array, like in my example code? and if it's set, run the beforeSend/success code?

Answer (score -1):

How about

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function() {
      $('.element button').prop('disabled', true).addClass('animate-load').parents('html').addClass('busy');
    },
    complete: function() {
      $('.element button').prop('disabled', false).removeClass('animate-load').parents('html').removeClass('busy');
    }
});
```

Comment: you're missing a `: function()`

Comment: One problem with this method is if you ever pass one of those options to an actual `$.ajax` call it will override the behavior defined here.  It would be better to use an `$.ajaxPrefilter` to add this functionality.